# Join two SELECT queries with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out joining two querys into one. Or if I should or need to.

I have this...

```
    SELECT      
    cd.SalesRep_ID AS CustomersSalesRep_ID
    FROM `CustomerDetails` cd
    WHERE cd.Customer_ID = $Customer_ID
```

That works fine and gives me the 'SalesRep_ID' that I'm looking for.

But I need that 'SalesRep_ID' for the next query like this...

```
    SELECT      
    cd.IsSalesRep, cd.RepCom, cd.SalesRep_ID, sr.RepDispName, sr.DefaultRepCom

    FROM `CustomerDetails` cd
    LEFT JOIN `SalesReps` sr
    ON cd.SalesRep_ID = sr.SalesRep_ID
    WHERE cd.Customer_ID = $Customer_ID
    AND sr.SalesRep_ID = $CustomersSalesRep_ID
```

Using both of these produces the results I'm looking for. However can they be joined together, or do they do to be?

Comment: The first query is already joined into the second... I'm confused.   What is wrong with the output you are receiving from your second query?

Comment: Nothing. I get the results I'm looking for. I want to know they the two can be joined into one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, this is what you're after:

```
SELECT cd.SalesRep_ID AS CustomersSalesRep_ID,
       cd.IsSalesRep,
       cd.RepCom,
       cd.SalesRep_ID,
       sr.RepDispName,
       sr.DefaultRepCom
FROM   CustomerDetails AS cd LEFT JOIN SalesReps AS sr USING(SalesRep_ID)
WHERE  cd.Customer_ID = $Customer_ID
```

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. USING is what I'm missing.

Comment: @Monty: Actually, no.  Adding `cd.SalesRep_ID` to the columns that you `SELECT` is what made the difference.  I prefer `USING` over `ON` only because it's both more concise and it eliminates one version of the identical columns from the resulting `JOIN`, thereby preventing annoying "ambiguous column" errors: it doesn't actually make any difference to your problem in this case.